# I want to compress large JSON object in javascript and decompress it in java

Tags: javascript, java, compression

I want to compress large  JSON object in javascript and decompress it in java.What is best compression Algorithm that will support this?

Continuing on same,i tried to use gzip,facing issue with that..

"*I have javascript as client side and Java Jboss Resteasy on my server side.I tried your approach it is not working.I used zlib library in javascript to compress using Gzip and used Content Encoding as gzip ,also Gzip annotation at Jboss server side to automatically decompress it.It was not working.Also,I tried to use InputStreamReader to decompress in java ,it was throwing "Data not in Gzip Format" error.Can you please help me here ,if possible can you paste an example code for the same*"

Code in Javascript

```
 zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify($scope.jsonCompressCheck),function(err, buffer) {
            if (!err) {
              console.log("USing gzip: ");
              console.log("Byte Length: "+Buffer.byteLength(buffer));
              console.log(sizeof(buffer));

             $scope.compressed = buffer;
             var buf2 = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify($scope.jsonCompressCheck));

        $http.post(ATS_URL + ATS_INSTANCE + '/rest/private/decompress/' + clientName + '/gzipdecompress', ($scope.compressed), {

            contentType: 'application/json',
            contentEncoding: 'gzip'

        }).success(function (data, status, headers) {

            console.log("Output Response :- "+data+" Headers: "+headers+"  status: "+status);

        }).error(function (reason) {

            console.log(" Error reason "+reason);
        });
```

Java Code here : Jboss RestEasy 
Endpoint

```
@POST @NoCache
@ApiOperation(value = "Decompress Given Compressed Json object Using Gzip",
                    response = ElasticSearchResults.class, position = 0)
@Path("/{client}/gzipdecompress")
public String gzipJsonDecompress(
        @ApiParam(value = "This required field should be the client name as defined in the datasources.", required = true)
        @PathParam("client") String client,
        @GZIP byte[] compressedObject) throws ATSException {
     return decompressService.gzipJsonDecompress(client,compressedObject);
}
```

Implementation Code

```
 public String gzipJsonDecompress(String client,byte[] compressedObject)throws ATSException{

    validateDomain(client);

    try
    {    InputStream inputStream = new 
         ByteArrayInputStream(compressedObject);
        GZIPInputStream gzipInput = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream); //Not working here  
         ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate compression may be GZip. You can upload the content compressed using GZip and set up the server to handle Content-Encoding header so that it is automatically uncompressed on the server end. Look at following link.
[enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/56700/is-it-possible-to-enable-http-compression-for-requests)

Comment: I have javascript as client side and Java Jboss Resteasy on my server side.I tried your approach it is not working.I used zlib library in javascript to compress using Gzip and used Content Encoding as gzip ,also Gzip annotation at Jboss server side to automatically decompress it.It was not working.Also,I tried to use InputStreamReader to decompress in java ,it was throwing "Data not in Gzip Format" error.Can you please help me here ,if possible can you paste an example code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Compress a normal JSON object as a LZW string:**

var lzwString = JSONC.pack( json );

**Decompress using java:**
String input = BinaryStdIn.readString();
TST<Integer> st = new TST<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
     st.put("" + (char) i, i);
int code = R+1;  // R is codeword for EOF

while (input.length() > 0) {
String s = st.longestPrefixOf(input);  // Find max prefix match s.
BinaryStdOut.write(st.get(s), W);      // Print s's encoding.
int t = s.length();
if (t < input.length() && code < L)    // Add s to symbol table.
    st.put(input.substring(0, t + 1), code++);
    input = input.substring(t);            // Scan past s in input.
}
BinaryStdOut.write(R, W);
BinaryStdOut.close();
```